# Thread for Win32 and WinCE platform

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-ce

I am trying to write a simple console application which needs to work on both Win32 and WinCE(6.0). I`m using visual studio 2013 to develope my Win32 console application. Will the same application work for WinCE?

Also I`m creating threads using _beginthread, will that be compatible with WinCE?
Other like, assert.h, process.h, iostream, sstream, map, deque, vector, list

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the same application work for WinCE?

I am developing application that is compiled both on desktop and (among others) on WindowsCE 5.0 (using Standard SDK). So it is possible, but you have to remember that WindowsCE API is a subset of desktop API. I am using Visual Studio 2005, I thought that Windows CE development is available only up to VS2008.

> Also I`m creating threads using _beginthread, will that be compatible with WinCE?

no, you will have to abstract out thread creation (even with define), use CreateThread under windows ce.

> assert.h, iostream, sstream, map, deque, vector, list

yes, full STL is available - also you can use STLPort. Depending on your device you might not have a console on it, I at least work on devices where `std::cout` simply is not available.

> process.h

no, at least under WinCE 5.0